# Why can't WebStorm list my installed package after I change npm default directory?

Tags: node.js, npm, webstorm

Here is the result of executing command `npm config ls -l`:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>npm config ls -l
; cli configs
long = true
user-agent = "npm/2.15.1 node/v4.4.4 win32 x64"

; builtin config undefined
cache = "D:\\npm-cache"
prefix = "D:\\npm"

; default values
access = null
always-auth = false
bin-links = true
browser = null
ca = null
; cache = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache" (overridden)
cache-lock-retries = 10
cache-lock-stale = 60000
cache-lock-wait = 10000
cache-max = null
cache-min = 10
cafile = undefined
cert = null
color = true
depth = null
description = true
dev = false
editor = "notepad.exe"
engine-strict = false
fetch-retries = 2
fetch-retry-factor = 10
fetch-retry-maxtimeout = 60000
fetch-retry-mintimeout = 10000
force = false
git = "git"
git-tag-version = true
global = false
globalconfig = "D:\\npm\\etc\\npmrc"
globalignorefile = "D:\\npm\\etc\\npmignore"
group = 0
heading = "npm"
https-proxy = null
if-present = false
ignore-scripts = false
init-author-email = ""
init-author-name = ""
init-author-url = ""
init-license = "ISC"
init-module = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\.npm-init.js"
init-version = "1.0.0"
json = false
key = null
link = false
local-address = undefined
loglevel = "warn"
; long = false (overridden)
maxsockets = 50
message = "%s"
node-version = "4.4.4"
npat = false
onload-script = null
optional = true
parseable = false
; prefix = "D:\\nodejs" (overridden)
production = false
proprietary-attribs = true
proxy = null
rebuild-bundle = true
registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
rollback = true
save = false
save-bundle = false
save-dev = false
save-exact = false
save-optional = false
save-prefix = "^"
scope = ""
searchexclude = null
searchopts = ""
searchsort = "name"
shell = "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe"
shrinkwrap = true
sign-git-tag = false
spin = true
strict-ssl = true
tag = "latest"
tag-version-prefix = "v"
tmp = "C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp"
umask = 0
unicode = true
unsafe-perm = true
usage = false
user = 0
; user-agent = "npm/{npm-version} node/{node-version} {platform} {arch}" (overridden)
userconfig = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\.npmrc"
version = false
versions = false
viewer = "browser"
```

And I have added `D:\nodejs\` and `D:\npm` to `PATH`.

While in WebStorm the list of npm package become empty, like this:

[image: setting]

How can I let WebStorm list all the package including global?

Comment: 1) If you execute `npm list -g --depth=0` in built-in Terminal -- will it list them there? 2) Have you tried restarting IDE after making such changes?

Comment: Yes,all of the global package can be listed out,but when I restart IDE,there is still nothing.  T_T,is this a bug?

Comment: What `where npm` shows you? The best I can think of ... is that `Npm package` field from your screenshot should have different value. No other ideas from me...